# Problem in Sequential limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

i want to solve this question but i don't know what way i use :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\binom n 1} {n} +\frac {\binom n 2} {n^2} + \cdots + \frac {\binom n n}{n^n} $$

Comment: I wonder if what was meant was $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\binom n 1} {n} +\frac {\binom n 2} {n^2} + \cdots + \frac {\binom n n}{n^n}. $$ This would require $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ to appear on both sides, and would have $a_n$ rather than $an$ on the left side. $\qquad$

Comment: oh really sorry.

Comment: If that's what was intended, could you edit the question?

Comment: i'm a newbie in MathJax and it was really hard for me.

Comment: If you right-click on the notation in my comment above, you can see the MathJax code for it and then you can just copy and paste it. (But now I've edited the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sum is
$$-1+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac1{n^k}=
-1+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n.$$
This has a well-known limit...

Answer (score 1):

***hint***

Newton's binomial $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k x^ky^{n-k}$

With $y=1$ and $x=\frac 1 n$

and the fact that $\lim_{ n\to \infty} (1+ \frac 1 n)^n =e$

Comment: People use the word "hint" too much. This is really a sketch rather than a hint.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelHardy next time I will just give a hint...

Comment: I don't object to posting a sketch, and sometimes I do that myself, but I would use a different word.

Comment: no problem @MichaelHardy I do agree with you...it wasn't a hint at all...more a sketch as you said